# Mouse and Touchpad options

Tags: mouse, touchpad, vaio

## The Problem

The options for Mouse and Touchpad are combined on one page see image below
[image]

The pointer speed moves, but doesn't change anything and is not saved when I exit, also the two finger scroll is greyed out. Also I feel that there should be a lot more options available.

### Equipment

Sony Vaio VGN-AR71E laptop

## Question

Can anyone advise which drivers to install please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solved

I found the answer to this in the Ubuntu Software Centre! Make a search for Synapstiks and download the 'Synapstiks Touchpad management' tool, it works a treat.